# sympy - cos of a list of variables

Tags: python, sympy

I try to implement a cos function of a list with variables with sympy. Here an easy example:

```
    from sympy import *
    x = Symbol('x')
    cos([x+1,x+2,x+3])
```

But then the error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_Number'
```

occurs and not what I've expected  `array([cos([x+1]),cos([x+2]),cos([x+3])])`.
Is there an easy way to use the cos as `numpy.cos()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Python builtin `map` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to apply `sympy.cos` to each element in the list:

```
import sympy as sy
x = sy.Symbol('x')
print(list(map(sy.cos, [x+1,x+2,x+3])))
```

yields

```
[cos(x + 1), cos(x + 2), cos(x + 3)]
```